# Installing Bootstrap into Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

So I'm working on my first rails project and I am trying to install bootstrap, but I'm having some issues. I followed the directions on the github page but when I did everything and reloaded my page I received this error: Can someone please help me?

[image: Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong]

Comment: restart the server? and please name the files as filename.scss . and extra css doesn't make a difference

Comment: You are right, it works now!

Comment: User uses sass, so naming them *.sass would be more appropriate ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting your code in wrong path.Please edit the name of the file `app/assets/stylesheets.css` to  `app/assets/stylesheets.css.scss` and then put `@import "bootstrap-sprockets";` and `@import "bootstrap";` in this file.

For more details visit https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but that gem does not work at this time, I recommend you use the CDN or others css of boostrap.
I did not get to use that gem.

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Hope that helps.